# having problems passing javascript variable to php file in the url

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code right now :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ktitle =        $('.hiddentwo').text();
$('div#tab2').load('morefour.php?title=ktitle');
});
```

but the php file doesn't seem to be getting this variable...am I doing something wrong?

I echo something in the php file and I see the text. Also when I echo the $ktitle in the php file I get 'kitle'...that should not be happening :p. This is a stupid question, but I just want to know how to store that variable in the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div#tab2').load( 'morefour.php?title=' + encodeURIComponent(ktitle) );
```

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
   $('div#tab2').load("morefour.php", {
       title:ktitle
   });
```

or

```
$('div#tab2').load('morefour.php?title='+ktitle);
```

UPDATE

In the first case, the data are passed to the script via POST, in the second via GET.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're hardcoding the `?title` to "ktitle". If you want to replace this with a variable, you need to concatenate the variable with `'morefour.php?title=' + ktitle`.